# Circular imageview dissappears in listview after fling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Im generating a feed full of images (similar to instagram post) using Glide for loading images and user's profile picture. After i get the data from server, i load the Url's of images inside the listitem. Initally All items are being loaded properly.

The issue is that when i fast scroll the listview, user profile picture dissappears and that view doesnt respond to onClick Events. Please explain why this happens and how can i resolve this?

XML layout of each list Item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/userheader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

 <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/realdp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/nodp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/realdp"
    android:text="handle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/realdp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/realdp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/uploadtime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="time"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlimg"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/handle">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgpost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>
  </RelativeLayout> 

 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlimg"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

   <com.sivaram.fishograph.FlipImageView
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/hook_unlike"/>

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likesnum"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/comment" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/more" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/likesnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/like"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/like"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/like"
    android:text="likes"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#440011" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/comnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="comments"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#440011" />

   </RelativeLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>  

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userheader"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Caption"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dummy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/caption"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />            
 </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code for generating feed:

```
public class Feed extends Fragment implements OnScrollListener
{ 
    String handle;
    ListView lvposts;
    Jsparser jp;
    int width,height;
    int maxMemory;
    int currentFirstVisibleItem ;
    int currentVisibleItemCount;
    PostAdapter pa;
    ArrayList<eachpost> posts;
    int value = 1;
    boolean isLoading = false;
    int photoid;
    private List<String> myData;
    Boolean tapped = false, Loading= false;
    SharedPreferences spf;
    ArrayList<String> likes;
    public Feed()
    {
      super();
    }

    Feed(String handle)
    {
      super();
      photoid = 99999999;
      this.handle = handle; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
     super.onCreate(b);
     maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
     final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
     spf = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        likes = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup vg,  Bundle b)
    { 
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.allposts, vg, false);
      ActionBar ab = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
      ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
      ab.hide();
      lvposts = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvposts);
      jp = new Jsparser();
      Display d = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      width = d.getWidth();
      height = d.getHeight();
      lvposts.setOnScrollListener(this);
      posts = new ArrayList<eachpost>();
      pa = new     PostAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.postcontent,posts,inflater);
      Loading = true;
      lvposts.setAdapter(pa);
      new GetData(photoid).execute(); 
      return v;
     }

class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
  {
    String msg;
    Integer limit,success=0;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Bitmap dpbm;
    GetData(int l)
    {
        limit = l;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute()
    {
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> lp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        lp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("handle",handle));
        lp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photoid",limit.toString()));
        JSONObject job = jp.makeHttpRequest("server/getfeed.php", "POST", lp);

        try
        {
          Log.d("json", job.toString());
          success = job.getInt("success");
          msg = job.getString("message");
          if(success==1)
          {
            JSONArray ja = job.getJSONArray("posts");
            for(int c = 0; c<ja.length(); c++)
            {
              JSONObject jb = ja.getJSONObject(c);
              posts.add(new eachpost(jb.getString("handle"),jb.getString("url"), jb.getString("caption"),
              jb.getString("uldatetime"), jb.getInt("likescount"), jb.getInt("comcount"), jb.getString("dpurl"), jb.getInt("isliked"),jb.getInt("photoid") ));
            }
          }
          else
          {
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;
     }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String url)
    {
     Loading = false;
     if(success==1)
      {    
        photoid = posts.get(posts.size()-1).getPhotoid();
        Log.d("last id",photoid+"");
        Log.d("Length of posts",""+posts.size());
        pa.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    }

  }

class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<eachpost> 
{
  ViewHolder vholder;
  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File dir = new File (root + ".feed");
  Map<Integer,View> myViews;
    public PostAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<eachpost> list, LayoutInflater li) {
        super(context, R.layout.postcontent, list); 
        myViews = new HashMap<Integer,View>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos,View v,ViewGroup vg)
    {   
      final eachpost post = posts.get(pos);
      final String imgurl = post.getPhotoUrl();
      String dpurl = post.getDpurl();
      int isliked = post.getIsliked();
      View row = myViews.get(pos);
      if(row == null)
      { 
        row = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.postcontent,vg,false); 
        row.setMinimumHeight(height);
        vholder = new ViewHolder();
        vholder.handle = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.handle));
        vholder.caption = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.caption));
        vholder.likesnum = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.likesnum));
        vholder.comnum = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comnum));
        vholder.uploadtime = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.uploadtime));
        vholder.photo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgpost);
        vholder.feeddp = (CircularImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.realdp);
        vholder.like = (FlipImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.like);
            LayoutParams lp = vholder.photo.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = width;

        vholder.handle.setText(post.getHandle());
        vholder.caption.setText(post.getCaption());
        vholder.likesnum.setText(post.getLikes()+"");
        vholder.comnum.setText(post.getComments()+"");
        vholder.uploadtime.setText(post.getUl());
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hook_like);
        vholder.like.setFlippedDrawable(d);
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load("server/"+imgurl).into(vholder.photo);

        if(dpurl.contains("http"))
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(dpurl).into(vholder.feeddp);
        else
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load("server/"+dpurl).into(vholder.feeddp);
        Log.d("image loading", dpurl + "-" + imgurl);
        if(isliked==1)
             {
               vholder.like.setFlipped(true,false);
               likes.add(imgurl);
             }

        vholder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View temp = myViews.get(pos);
                final FlipImageView like = (FlipImageView) temp.findViewById(R.id.like);
                final TextView likesnum = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.likesnum);
                like.toggleFlip();

                if(!likes.contains(imgurl))
                   {
                    posts.get(pos).incrementLikes(handle);
                    likes.add(posts.get(pos).getPhotoUrl());
                    likesnum.setText(posts.get(pos).getLikes()+"");
                  }
                else
                  {
                    likes.remove(posts.get(pos).getPhotoUrl());
                    posts.get(pos).decrementLikes(handle);
                    likesnum.setText(posts.get(pos).getLikes()+"");
                  }

            }
        });

        row.setTag(vholder);
        myViews.put(pos, row);
      }

       return row;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return true;
    }

}  //end of adapter class

static class ViewHolder {
        TextView handle;
        TextView caption;
        TextView likesnum;
        TextView comnum;
        TextView uploadtime;
        ImageView photo;
        CircularImageView feeddp;
        FlipImageView like;
   }

  @Override
  public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
   if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
    /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
    /*** do the work for load more date! ***/

        if(currentFirstVisibleItem > (currentVisibleItemCount - 2) && Loading!=true)
        {
            new GetData(photoid).execute();
        }       
   }
  }

 @Override
 public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;

 }  
}
```

Comment: I think problem arise b'coz of you haven't use `ViewHolder` pattern properly inside `getView`

Comment: @kishorejethava I tried with adding the line vholder = row.getTag() . Issue still exist. Im storing the views in hashmap there is no use of view Holder right.

Answer (score 0):

When loading multiple images there is always caching problem when using Async Tasks. I recommend an open source library [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). It will load the images and cache it. After that most probably, your fast scroll problem will solve.
The cause can also be the size of the images being received. Picasso has methods by which you can resize the image before putting it onto the image view

Comment: But isn't Glide faster and better than Picasso?

Answer (score 0):

try with this modified `getView`

```
@Override
public View getView(final int pos,View v,ViewGroup vg)
{   
  final eachpost post = posts.get(pos);
  final String imgurl = post.getPhotoUrl();
  String dpurl = post.getDpurl();
  int isliked = post.getIsliked();
  View row = myViews.get(pos);
  if(row == null)
  { 
   row = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.postcontent,vg,false); 
   row.setMinimumHeight(height);
   vholder = new ViewHolder();
   vholder.handle = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.handle));
   vholder.caption = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.caption));
   vholder.likesnum = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.likesnum));
   vholder.comnum = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comnum));
   vholder.uploadtime = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.uploadtime));
   vholder.photo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgpost);
   vholder.feeddp = (CircularImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.realdp);
   vholder.like = (FlipImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.like);
       LayoutParams lp = vholder.photo.getLayoutParams();
   lp.width = width;
   lp.height = width;

   row.setTag(vholder); //changed here setTag()
 }else{
     vholder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag(); //changed here getTag()
 }

 vholder.handle.setText(post.getHandle());
 vholder.caption.setText(post.getCaption());
 vholder.likesnum.setText(post.getLikes()+"");
 vholder.comnum.setText(post.getComments()+"");
 vholder.uploadtime.setText(post.getUl());
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hook_like);
 vholder.like.setFlippedDrawable(d);
 Glide.with(getActivity()).load("server/"+imgurl).into(vholder.photo);

 if(dpurl.contains("http"))
     Glide.with(getActivity()).load(dpurl).into(vholder.feeddp);
 else
     Glide.with(getActivity()).load("server/"+dpurl).into(vholder.feeddp);
 Log.d("image loading", dpurl + "-" + imgurl);
 if(isliked==1)
      {
        vholder.like.setFlipped(true,false);
        likes.add(imgurl);
      }

 vholder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         View temp = myViews.get(pos);
         final FlipImageView like = (FlipImageView) temp.findViewById(R.id.like);
         final TextView likesnum = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.likesnum);
         like.toggleFlip();

         if(!likes.contains(imgurl))
            {
             posts.get(pos).incrementLikes(handle);
             likes.add(posts.get(pos).getPhotoUrl());
             likesnum.setText(posts.get(pos).getLikes()+"");
           }
         else
           {
             likes.remove(posts.get(pos).getPhotoUrl());
             posts.get(pos).decrementLikes(handle);
             likesnum.setText(posts.get(pos).getLikes()+"");
           }

     }
 });
 myViews.put(pos, row);
  }
  return row;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the vholder.like listener is working properly except for the first list item.

Comment: Actually, even with this code listview behaves weirdly. That is when i fast scroll like does'nt work. The FlipimageView doesn't flip